# How to resolve Keil uVision 5.0 compilation errors?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

In an effort to learn Embedded System Programming I recently installed Keil uVision 5.0. I am using a STM32F development board. At this point all I am interested in is getting [STM32 L1 Tutorial #1: Hello, World! (LED Blink)](http://mightydevices.com/?p=121) code complied and loaded into the microcontroller. While attempting to build the code I got the following errors. What is the cause of this error?

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 3 (build 300)', folder: 
'C:\Doc\Programs\Keil52\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'Target'
Error instantiating RTE components
Error #540: 'Keil::Device:Startup:1.0.0' component is not available for target 'Target'
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:00
```

Comment: It seems programming questions aren't enough welcomed here, even the ones related closely to engineering. I think not all of the reviewers think it is okay, but if your question would be closed, I suggest give a try to http://stackoverflow.com .

Comment: @peterh, I am seeking help to configure a Keil to work with a STM32 microcontroller. I don't understand what do you mean that not all of the reviewers think it is okay.

Comment: Behind your question, there is a reviewing mechanism where a vote decides if a question is off-topic on the site or not. You can't see this vote, but if you remain between us and put new questions and answers, first you will see that, and later you will be able to take part in it. I voted for this question to remain here, others could think rather you should try http://stackoverflow.com with programming questions. Their reason that they don't want a programming site, but an engineering site. I think we could (should) be more lenient in border cases. Anyways, in the case of a closure

Comment: it is important to not take it personally, only simply re-ask on the stackoverflow - and, if you have an engineering question in the future, don't leave us but ask this (actually, *your reputation will grow even in the case of a closed question*). The reputation is the bold number below your nick, currently it is 8. If you post more questions or answer them, it will grow like a rocket, because the site mainly loves the high quality content.

Comment: @peterh  **general computing hardware and software** are off topic on stackoverflow. [What is the difference between RTOS and Embedded Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871579/what-is-the-difference-between-rtos-and-embedded-linux)

Answer (score 2):

On Keil uVision goto Project > Manage > Run-Time Environment. You will get a screen like the following.

[image: Keil Run-Time Environment]

Your device is not properly configure as indicated by the Red box. Click on the Device + to expand. Then select the appropriate "System and Start up file"

Also you may try the resolve button in bottom.

Here is screen shot of when the error is fixed.

[image]